# slurm - sbatch job array for parallel execution of serial jobs filling each node using wrap command

Tags: arrays, slurm

I have a file with one command per line like:

```
myprog.sh <args abc>
myprog.sh <args def>
```

I am trying to submit these as jobs in an array. The array should use 1 host, and all the cpus on that host. Instead, each array is using 2 hosts, and executing both commands on both hosts.

What I'd like:

```
host1
  - myprog.sh <args abc> slurm-1_1.out
  - myprog.sh <args def> slurm-1_2.out
```

slurm-1_1.out would have the stdout from job 1, and slurm1_2.out would have the stdout from job2. Instead, what is happening is this:

```
host1
  - myprog.sh <args abc> slurm-1_1.out
  - myprog.sh <args def> slurm-1_1.out
host2
  - myprog.sh <args abc> slurm-1_2.out
  - myprog.sh <args def> slurm-1_2.out
```

So each job is being duplicated on each host.

My sbatch command looks like:

```
sbatch -p small --nodes=1 -w host1 --cpus-per-task=1 --mem-per-cpu=3G --array=1-2 --wrap="myprog.sh <args abc> & myprog.sh <args def> & wait"
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Array jobs are for completely independent workloads. You want the jobs running concurrently on the same machine, so an array doesn't fit that case. You could go for a single job with two tasks though:

```
#SBATCH -p small
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks=2
#If you want access to all CPU and memory:
#SBATCH --exclusive

srun -n 1 myprog.sh <args abc> > first.out & 
srun -n 1 myprog.sh <args def> > second.out &
wait
```

Depending on your cluster setup, you might need the `--exact` flag and more memory specifications for `srun`. This changed a bit in recent versions. You should be able to do this in one line with a wrap command aswell, but as that is not really readable, I prefer to write the jobscript.

Comment: I see. It's strange to me because completely independent workloads can run on the same machine, that's the point of having a 64 core machine :D. I'm switching over from LSF and this is trivial in LSF. I'll try this out and post back if it seems like it'll do the trick.

Comment: The main issue with this is that it creates one job. a job is supposed to be an independent task. I appreciate the help anyway.

Comment: If they are independent, why do they have to be on the same host?

Comment: because hosts cost money and consistently underutilizing the cores on a host is bad for business. if I wanted to use 1 core per machine, I would buy several one core machines. Not several large core machines, each using only 1 core. Make sense?

Comment: Not really. Are your nodes used exclusively for one job at a time? Meaning that a one core job will block a whole node?

Comment: So, I appreciate the answer here. Turns out this was a cloud issue and not a slurm issue. I'm using an elastic cluster in the cloud, and the way the software calculates the node capacity for compute nodes is incorrect because it doesn't have the notion of sockets. I got around it by adding an extension to the slurm.conf